# Apache Spark - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataInputStream

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to install spark (without hadoop).

Java version: 1.8.0_202

Spark version: spark-3.3.1

Python version: 3.7.15

When I execute spark-shell or pyspark I got this error:

```
[spark@de ~]$ spark-shell
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataInputStream
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 7 more
```

**Pyspark:**

```
[spark@de ~]$ pyspark
Python 3.7.15 (default, Nov  1 2022, 23:18:36)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44.0.3)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataInputStream
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 7 more
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/spark-3.3.1/python/pyspark/shell.py", line 36, in <module>
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized()
  File "/opt/spark-3.3.1/python/pyspark/context.py", line 417, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
  File "/opt/spark-3.3.1/python/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 106, in launch_gateway
    raise RuntimeError("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

What is wrong? do I need hadoop? so why there is a download option called *spark-3.3.1-bin-without-hadoop.tgz*? (without hadoop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Spark [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/#downloading):

> Spark uses Hadoop’s client libraries for HDFS and YARN. Downloads are pre-packaged for a handful of popular Hadoop versions. Users can also download a “Hadoop free” binary and run Spark with any Hadoop version by augmenting Spark’s classpath.

You do not need a Hadoop cluster to be set up, but you do need some Hadoop libraries.

For your case, it seems you don't have a Hadoop cluster set up, so you should go with spark-with-hadoop binaries.

Comment: Thanks! Now I understood the meaning of "without hadoop". I have downloaded with hadoop and it's working fine.